# php / regex convert multiple paragraphs to one paragraph with line breaks

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, string, text

I want to convert a string like this

```
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>three</p>
```

to this

```
<p>one<br>two<br>three</p>
```

(If it is only one paragraph tag then it would remain unchanged)

So I know the regex would basically just need to replace each `</p><p>` pair with a `<br>`,  I could just str_replace() `</p><p>` with `<br>` but there will be possible line breaks or spaces between the closing and opening p tag.

So using regex, something like this. But this strips out 'two' (because it is between an ending and opening p tag). It also appears to break on new lines?

```
<?php
$string = '<p>one</p><p>two</p><p>three</p>';
$string2 = '<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>three</p>';
$pattern = '~</p>.*<p>~';
$replacement = '<br>';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string2);

// Outputs "<p>one<br>three</p><p>one</p>" and "<p>one</p>
// <p>two</p>
// <p>three</p>"
```

Does anyone know how to fix that regex or know of a better method?

(I am using Wordpress in case there is some helper function)

Cheers! :)

Comment: So you only need to ‍replace `</p>\s*<p>` with `<br>`?

Comment: `$pattern = '~</p>[^/]*<p>~';` seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
<?php
$string = '<p>one</p><p>two</p><p>three</p>';
$string2 = '<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>three</p>';
$pattern = '~</p>\s*<p>~u';
$replacement = '<br>';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string) . PHP_EOL. preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string2);
```

See [proof](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4BLpbikKDMvXcFWQd2mwC4/L9VGv8AOyCopz4exMopSwaLq1jDVRqjKuRDqudA1FCSWlKQW5YE01IHEYoq1gErqSkFyRakFOYnJqbmpeSVgA5OKQFq4UpMz8hUKilLT46EKNGCm6Cgg6wHyIM7RVNBTCPAIiHf199EjSaORpjXX//8A).

Result:

```php
<p>one<br>two<br>three</p>
<p>one<br>two<br>three</p>
```

Comment: Ah \s* it! Seems obvious now, I was overthinking it, thank you! 